# Featured view Title position?

Tags: joomla-3.x, view

I would like to change how articles are viewed for the featured list view used for my homepage.
Normally articles display there title first above intro image and content.

Is it possible to change it so that the title is positioned right of the intro image like the content?

Screenshot example, where I would like it from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Joomla's [template override](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core),

by using this method you can override all Joomla core template styles.

For com_content

```
PATH_TO_JOOMLA/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php
to
TEMPLATE_NAME/html/com_content/article/default.php
```

If you want to change featured view only.then like below.

```
TEMPLATE_NAME/html/com_content/featured/default.php
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: I am familiar with the use of template override. But I'm not very good at php coding, so I'm not sure how to alter that code to achieve the following.

Comment: check the $this->item->title in default_item.php and change it position.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Tried moving that around to line 146, but the title always ended up being below the Details part, publish date, author etc.
Ended up moving the entire code from line 25-136 to line 146 below the code for the intro image. Seem to be looking and working good.